# Validate DateTime object in Ruby

Tags: ruby, datetime, object, validation

A constructor in following code receives a DateTime object in the parameter

```
class Test
    attr_accessor :dateTime

    # Takes DateTime object as input
    def initialize(dateTime)
        @dateTime = dateTime
    end
end
```

How can I validate if dateTime parameter passed to the constructor is valid DateTime object or not?

One way to find out is by using:

```
if dateTime.class == DateTime
```

But is there a better way to do it?

Remember, dateTime is DateTime object and not a string

Comment: By "valid", I meant an instance of DateTime (or it's subclass)

Answer (score 4):

You can check it by `dateTime.is_a?(DateTime)` it will return boolean

Answer (score 4):

Maybe use `is_a?` or `kind_of?`, to be flexible with potential subclasses.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001033

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `is_a?` method, this way if the object is an instance of your target class (DateTime) or a subclass then you can accept it:

```
dateTime.is_a?(DateTime)
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to make sure that you get an instance of DateTime (or a subclass), then the other "is `is_a?`" answers are what you want.

However, you should consider being a little more forgiving of your inputs. What if someone hands you a string like "2011-06-28 23:31:11"? To most people, that's a DateTime even though Ruby thinks it is an instance of String. If you want to be friendlier, you could try [`DateTime.parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/classes/DateTime.html#M000485) this:

```
begin
    dt = dt.is_a?(DateTime) ? dt : DateTime.parse(dt)
rescue ArgumentError
    # Do your failure stuff here
end
```

Or, if you're in Rails:

```
begin
    dt = dt.to_datetime
rescue ArgumentError, NoMethodError
    # Do your failure stuff here
end
```

These approaches give you a lot of flexibility without losing anything in the process. Be forgiving of your input but strict in your output.

For reference, in Rails 3, the following have `to_datetime` methods:

- [Date](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#method-i-to_datetime)
- [DateTime](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-to_datetime)
- [Time](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-to_datetime)
- [String](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-to_datetime)

Comment: The second suggestion for Rails, doesn't seem to work for an empty string:

`dt = dt.to_datetime # = nil`

Comment: @Chris: `dt = dt.presence` and add an explicit `nil` check. Or `dt.presence.to_datetime` and trap it as a `NoMethodError`.